# Unable to combine python3.2 and 3.4 code (version control on import?)

Tags: python

Right, I have python code which imports 2 other python codes to execute, but I have a version problem code 1 requires python3.2 and lower (because it uses import GPIO and serial), code 2 requires python 3.4 (because it uses a updated version of socketCAN using AF_CAN)

When I import the 2 files is there a way for me to specify which version of python will compile and execute?

A simplified code form:

```
import time
import canBUSreader
import serialUSBreader
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

while True:
    try:
        print('trying to run code...')
        time.sleep(1)
        serialUSBreader.serial_main()

    except:
        print('failed')
        print('trying to run CANBUS code...')
        time.sleep(1)
        canBUSreader.can_main()
```

Or should I just keep trying to find ways of getting the imported libraries from python 3.2 to work on 3.4?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I would try to upgrade your 3.2 code, since this will be depricated at some point in the future.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't "compile" code with two different versions of python. When you run a python script, it's a single process running a single version of python.